# Координаты открытия контекстного меню MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

При открытии контекстного меню на Canvas нужно сохранять координаты меню в MainVM.

Через события это делается просто:

Xaml:

```
<Canvas ContextMenuOpening="Canvas_OnContextMenuOpening" />
```

Code-behind:

```
    class MainVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        public static Point ContextMenuPoint {get; set;}
    }

    //.....

    private void Canvas_OnContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {

        MainVM.ContextMenuPoint.X = e.CursorLeft;
        MainVM.ContextMenuPoint.Y = e.CursorTop;
    }
```

Как сделать тоже самое, но через команды?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, В случае с событиями мы просто делаем обработчик события  `ContextMenuOpening`. Т.е. я  кликаю ПКМ по `Canvas` — появляется контекстное меню. Координаты сохраняю в поле типа `Point`, например так `p.X = e.CursorLeft`. Все. В случае с командами же мне не ясна концепция.  Как сделать вызов команды, которая сохраняет координаты, при появлении меню, как забрать координаты меню и т.п.

Comment: Сделайте команду с параметром и в нем передавайте, что вам надо.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Зачем сохранять в VM? Это чисто вьюшная информация. Вам не должно этого хотеться.

Comment: @Bulson, Можете привести пример? Не понимаю как засунуть в параметр координаты меню.

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо! Это то, что я хотел узнать.

Comment: @maxwell: Пожалуйста!